# Hazekcast 4: cannon make remote call: com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperation

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I hava a project running with hazelcast 3.

I am trying to upgrade to hazelcast 4 but I keep getting the error:

```
cannon make remote call: com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperation
```

for every cache operation, and for every map in the cache. (sometimes it is RemovedOperation/GetOperation instaed of EntryOpertation).

I have no idea why this is happening in hazelcast 4, but not in hazelcast 3.

any help will be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Do you run in embedded mode or client-server?

Comment: I use embedded mode

Comment: If the Hz version is upgraded correctly on all nodes then you will have to provide more logging.. can you share full logs from the server that is throwing this error?